# Pandas - Assign value to subset of dataframe, based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have one large file covering all the markets, as well as a dict of symbols with the ticker as key. I only want to update the "submarket" column for "Mk 1" rows, which I know can easily be done with

```
table2.loc[table2['Market'] == "Mk 1" , ['Sub Market']]
```

I have been trying to assign "A" to submarket if the symbol (i.e. ticker) is in the dict other wise "B" but keep getting TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'

`dict`:

| key (ticker) | value (Name) |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | ABC Corp |
| XYZ | XYZ Corp |

table 2

| Market | Sub Market | Symbol |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mk1 |  | ABC |
| Mk 1 |  | ABC |
| Mk 1 |  | 123 |
| Mk 2 |  | 123 |
| Mk 3 |  | XYZ |

expected result

| Market | Sub Market | Symbol |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mk1 | A | ABC |
| Mk 1 | A | ABC |
| Mk 1 | B | 123 |
| Mk 2 |  | 123 |
| Mk 3 |  | XYZ |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `isin` and `map`:

```
df.loc[df['Market'].isin(['Mk 1', 'Mk1']), 'Sub Market'] = df['Symbol'].isin(dct).map({True:'A', False:'B'})
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Market Sub Market Symbol
0    Mk1          A    ABC
1   Mk 1          A    ABC
2   Mk 1          B    123
3   Mk 2          B    123
4   Mk 3          A    XYZ
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `numpy.where` with a boolean mask `msk` to filter the Market values equal to "Mk 1":

```
import numpy as np
msk = df2['Market'].isin(['Mk1', 'Mk 1'])
df2.loc[msk, 'Sub Market'] = np.where(df2.loc[msk, 'Symbol'].isin(dct['key (ticker)']), 'A', 'B')
```

Output:

```
  Market Sub Market Symbol
0    Mk1          A    ABC
1   Mk 1          A    ABC
2   Mk 1          B    123
3   Mk 2        NaN    123
4   Mk 3        NaN    XYZ
```

Note that it's spelt both `Mk1` and `Mk 1` (and I assume they are the same market, since you're treating them the same); that's why we need to use `isin` to construct `msk`, otherwise, it could be `df2['Market']=='Mk 1'`.